# create header file and test it in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, header-files, cs50

I have files in the same directory:

selection_sort.c

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include "selection_sort.h"

void selection_sort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] < values[min_index])
            {
                min_index = j; 
            }
        }

        int temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[min_index];
        values[min_index] = temp; 
    }
}
```

NOTE: This selection_sort() works fine in my previous use.

selection_sort.h

```
#include <cs50.h>
void selection_sort(int values[], int n);
```

Last file is the test file, named 
test_selection_sort.h

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "selection_sort.h"


int test_array[] = {2,4,7,5,9,1,3,6,8};

int main()
{
    int size = sizeof(test_array);
    selection_sort(test_array,size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf ("sorted %d", test_array[i]);
    }
}
```

But it shows undefined reference to 'selection_sort' when I compile:

```
$ make test_selection_sort

....undefined reference to `selection_sort'
```

I would like to understand the problem with the defined header file and my incorrect usage?

---

Edit:

I can make file now:

```
$gcc -o selection selection_sort.c test_selection_sort.c
$./selection
```

Comment: `int min_index = values[i];` --> `int min_index = i;`

Comment: `int size = sizeof(test_array);` --> `int size = sizeof(test_array)/sizeof(*test_array);`

Comment: `values[min_index] temp;` --> `values[min_index] = temp;`

Comment: The problem is nested somewhere in your Makefile. Please add it to your question for further help.

Comment: Show `Makefile`

Comment: You need to make sure your makefile compiles *both* `selection_sort.c` and  your `main.c` (or whatever it's called) and links them both into the executable, such as `gcc -c selection_sort.c; gcc -c main.c; gcc -o test main.o selection_sort.o` or something similar.

Comment: @Amy FYI there is a CS50 specific stack exchange site at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/. If you have other questions relating specifically to that course in the future, you might find answers quicker by searching there to start :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY might not be one - make will build an executable from the C file of the same name if it exists.

Comment: @Toby Thanks for your suggestion. I know that website. As my question is not the pset in the course. I just want to learn how to make a header file and use it.

Comment: @BlUEPIXY I need to learn how to write a Makefile now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message most likely means that you have failed to include the resulting .o file from compiling `selection_sort.c`.  It is not sufficient to merely include the header file, though that is important to do.

```
 gcc -c selection_sort.c
 gcc -c test_selection_sort.c
 gcc -o test_selection_sort selection_sort.o test_selection_sort.o
```

There are many other ways to accomplish this same thing.  If you are going to create multiple utility functions, consider using the `ar` tool to put them all into an object library and then include the library with the `-l` option.

Answer (score 4):

The C build system is an old one, and an include file is simply *included* in the source file normally to declare external functions or global variables. But it gives no hint for the linker about what modules are required. On the other hand, other languages such as C#, Java or Python *import* modules which both declares identifiers for the compilation part, but also declares the linker what already compiled module will be added to the program.

In C the programmer must both:

- use include files for the compiler
- explicitely link the different compilation units or library.

That's where a makefile can become handy by declaring only once how to build the executable and automatically rebuilds object files if the source was modified.

Alternatively, you could build with:

```
cc test_selection.c selection_sort.c -o test_selection
```

but it is less efficient because it consistently compiles both files even if one has not changed

Comment: It's a little overwhelming to me. I am taking course of CS50.  I did not see they have .o file included.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you didn't compile correctly.Fix your makefile.
Try this:

```
OBJS = selection_sort.o  test_selection_sort.o
TARGET =  test_selection_sort
CC = gcc
MODE = -std=c99
DEBUG = -g
DEPS = selection_sort.h
CFLAGS =  -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS =  -Wall $(DEBUG)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(MODE)

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(MODE)
```

just type

```
make
```

Comment: I find it very difficult for me to understand what's all of these meaning?

Comment: I never saw these before. A lot of stuff needs to be learnt in future.

Comment: @Amy: this is very much the way to go while you use `make`.  Your makefile lists the object files needed to create the executable.  Later, you may have some code in your own library, similar to the `-lcs50` library you also use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  It shows  : makefile:11 missing separator. stop.

Comment: @jonathanleffler    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(MODE)

Comment: @Amy: makefiles are fussy; the rules (recipe) lines such as `$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(MODE)` must be indented by an actual tab character, not just spaces. — Separately, in general, I'd keep the `-c` option out of `CFLAGS` and use it directly in `$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(MODE)`, and I'd pass `$(CFLAGS)` to the link line too.  That's tangential to your immediate issue, though.

Comment: @Amy as jonathan said you must use tab instead of spaces.Make just recognizes tab as separator. This tutorial clarifies all stuffs in this makefile.http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: @gurpinars A nice article to look through the makefile stuff.